# How to use one .js file for multiple .html pages using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one function in a JS file which should ideally be used by multiple html pages. I don't want to duplicate this function to another file. Currently, my js file starts like this:

```
(function(){
     var app = angular.module('Project1', []);
```

and the first html that has been using this JS is obviously called Project1.
I want 'Prject2' html to use this JS to, and I tried this:

```
(function(){
     var app = angular.module('Project1', 'Project2' []);
```

However, this doesn't work. Any idea of how I can utilize this AngularJS file for multiple html pages without duplicating the desired functions?

Answer (score 1):

simply add your js reference (and angular refrences) into both of your html pages
do note that add  them after adding angularjs references

Comment: i do the same for the must common functions i use. all in a js file and load it in the main html.

Comment: I did not quite understand this answer. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you mean to just add the .js reference to both html, this does not solve my problem since I still don't know which project I refer to in the angular.module braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your first module as you did in your first sample.

Your next sample can then use the 'Project1' by setting up a dependency to that module, like so:

```
var app = angular.module('Project2', ['Project1']);
```